# javax.swing.JOptionPane not displaying a result

Tags: java

Hi I am new to Java and programming.

My assignment is to write a program that calculates and prints the salesperson bonus for a General Sales company.  My class and test class compile correctly, I can enter an employee name, employee code, and sales, but after that I do not get a result displayed.

I need the test class to run so the employee can enter their name, their employee code, and their total sales and the screen will display their bonus based off their total sales.  For example if Bob, employee code 1, made over 10,000 dollars, they would receive a 500 dollar bonus.  I can enter a name, code, and sales, but after entering I only get a message saying to press any key to continue.  Thank you for any and all help.

here is my test class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SalesTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter name");
        int code = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter company code"));
        double sales = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your total sales"));
        double bonus = 0;

        if (sales > 0.0)
            switch (code) {
                //employee 1
                case 1:
                    if (sales >= 10000)
                        bonus = 500;
                    else
                        bonus = 200;
                    break;
                //employee 2
                case 2:
                    if (sales >= 20000)
                        bonus = 600;
                    else
                        bonus = 550;
                    break;
                //employee 3
                case 3:
                    if (sales < 10000)
                        bonus = 150;
                    break;
                //employee 4
                case 4:
                    if (sales < 10000)
                        bonus = 150;
                    break;
                //employee 5
                case 5:
                    if (sales < 10000)
                        bonus = 150;

                    System.out.println("Hello " + name + " your bonus is = " + bonus);
                    System.out.println("Error, please enter a positive value only");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the code correctly print the bonus?  (I'm unclear on whether the code is displaying no result at all, or only the JOptionPane isn't working.)

Comment: Please fix your indentation. With proper indentation you would instantly recognize your problem. Specifically, you could immediatly see that you print a result only if code is 5.

Comment: @markspace JOptionPane displays a result when code is 5, (although the result is incorrect), but if you were to enter 1,2,3, or 4, the only message that appears is the press any key to continue message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about to refactor your code and split two actions:

1. Receve data from user and calculation bonus
2. Print out user name and it bonus

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter name");
    int employeeCode = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter company code"));
    double sales = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your total sales"));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name + " your bonus is = " + calcBonus(employeeCode, sales));
}

private static double calcBonus(int employeeCode, double sales) {
    if (Double.compare(sales, 0) > 0) {
        if (employeeCode == 1)
            return Double.compare(sales, 100_000) >= 0 ? 500 : 200;
        if (employeeCode == 2)
            return Double.compare(sales, 200_000) >= 0 ? 600 : 550;
        if (employeeCode == 3 || employeeCode == 4 || employeeCode == 5)
            return Double.compare(sales, 100_000) < 0 ? 150 : 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```